# Typescript - How to return dynamic "object key" that comes from dynamic "prop key value"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to generate "dynamic object key" based of "prop key value" by picking specific object key value.

So let's say I pass in `{ name: 'someEntity', unrelatedKey: 123 }` and I would like to return `{ someEntity: 'ok' }`. How would one do that so the return value is typescript type defined? I've tried something like this but it does not work:

```
type GetExampleProps = {
  name: string
  unrelatedKey: number
}

type GetExampleRes<T> = {
  [key: T]: string
}

function getExample<T extends GetExampleProps> (props: T): GetExampleRes<T['name']> {
  return {
    [props.name]: 'ok'
  }
}

const example = getExample({ name: 'someEntity', unrelatedKey: 123 })

example.someEntity  // should be valid type string
example.hello       // should be invalid, missing key
```

Comment: If you're sure there are only going to be two keys you can use Object.keys(objectName) this gives you an array of object keys and you can traverse them to get where you need to be

Comment: I don't have guarantee how many keys there will be. That's why I would need to pick a specific key (in this case, "name") that i know it will have, and rest of the keys can be various unrelated keys that the function uses

Comment: so in case of multiple keys how does this work? also if you know that name will def be there then why not use objectName.name?

Comment: Can you give an example how would that work in this example so that the 'example.someEntity' would be valid definition?

Comment: Added as answer

Comment: Computed properties of generic types are unfortunately widened to string index signatures, which is considered a bug in TS (see [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948)) so any solution that involves narrower types will need to use something like a type assertion until and unless that is fixed.  See the linked q/a for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I am unable to do that without a type assertion, but as a temporary solution here it is:

```
type GetExampleProps<T extends PropertyKey = string> = {
  name: T;
  unrelatedKey: number;
};

function getExample<T extends PropertyKey>(
  props: GetExampleProps<T>
): {
  [K in T]: string;
} {
  const toRet = {
    [props.name]: "a string",
  };

  return toRet as { [K in T]: string };
}

const example = getExample({ name: "someEntity", unrelatedKey: 123 });

example.someEntity;
example.hello; // Property 'hello' does not exist on type '{ someEntity: string; }'
```

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten with this problem. Thank you. It does look a bit messy without type assertion but looks like it's the only solution. I'll keep the answer open for a bit

Comment: @Martyboy as far as I know this is as good as it gets, more or less.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function, this should work the way you need

```
const createObject = (obj: any) => {
    interface I {
        [name: string]: any;
    }
    const returnObj: I = {};
    returnObj[obj.name] = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => key !== "name");
    return returnObj;
};
```

Comment: No this doesn't answer the question. Problem is with typescript. I need to be able to define the dynamic key:value pair that the function returns. See the last 2 lines. "example.someEntity  // should be valid type string"

Comment: ok let me update it then

Comment: @Martyboy does this answer you